# Why is creating test delta table slow?

Tags: delta-lake

I am attempting to write some test cases for our spark logic by creating tiny input delta tables with known values. However I am noticing that the creation of a single item delta table is taking a very long time, about ~6 seconds per table. This quickly adds up and some test cases that use multiple tables are taking minutes to run!

I accept that spark tests will also be on the slow side, but similar tests with parquet have creation speeds of around 400ms which would be tolerable

I am running these on these tests on Windows which could be contributing to my issues but other formats seem to run fine and orders of magnitude faster

The test case i'm using to generate my timings is

```java
  "delta" should "create in a reasonable time" in {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[1]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // This takes ~15seconds but most of that can be attributed to spark warming up
    val preloadStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Seq(("test-1", "my-test"))
      .toDF("Id", "Source")
      .write
      .format("delta")
      .save(s"c:/tmp/test-${java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}")
    val preloadEnd = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Preload Elapsed time: " + (preloadEnd - preloadStart) + "ms")

    //actual test, why does this take ~6seconds?!?
    val testStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
    Seq(("test-2", "my-test"))
      .toDF("Id", "Source")
      .write
      .format("delta")
      .save(s"c:/tmp/test-${java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}")
    val testEnd = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Test Elapsed time: " + (testEnd - testStart) + "ms")
  }
```

Is there a configuration values I am missing or some otherway to speed up the delta table creation?

Comment: Recommended reading: _"Parallelizing with Apache Spark in Unexpected Ways"_ (Spark Summit 2019) section _"Parallel Job Submission and Schedulers"_  https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/parallelizing-with-apache-spark-in-unexpected-ways

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application >> but remember that you will need N threads to run N tasks in parallel

Comment: @SamsonScharfichter I could get some gains by parallelizing my test setup, although it seems to be a work around for the issue that doing operations on delta tables seems very slow

Answer (score 6):

Spark's default configurations are not designed for small jobs which usually happen in unit tests. Here are [the configurations](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/v0.5.0/build.sbt#L70) Delta Lake is using in unit tests:

```
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
  "-Dspark.ui.enabled=false",
  "-Dspark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false",
  "-Dspark.databricks.delta.snapshotPartitions=2",
  "-Dspark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5",
  "-Ddelta.log.cacheSize=3",
  "-Dspark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.parallelism=5",
  "-Xmx1024m"
)
```

You can also apply the same set of configurations to speed up your tests.